# How to return array in Swift after appending stuff to it?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, completionhandler

I am trying to build an array of items based off data I download from a collection of documents on Firebase. I start with an empty array, and then for each document I make an item based off the downloaded data from that document and append that item to the array. However, it returns an empty array. I have a feeling I need to do something with a completion handler but I can't quite understand how this would be done. Below is my code. Thanks!

```
func getDayData() -> [Item] {
    var myList = [Item]()
    let docs = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document("pK0tVBXvbFNhTZic3PIM").collection("Log").document("18-06-2020").collection("Items")
    docs.getDocuments() {(querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            //TODO
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                myList.append(Item(id: document.documentID, item: document.get("Item") as! String, category: document.get("Category") as! String, pieces: document.get("Pieces") as! Int))
            }
        }
    }
    return myList
}
```

Comment: Are you sure those `append` calls actually happen? It might be worth setting a breakpoint there. They might all be falling into that "TODO" hole.

Answer (score 4):

You can't wait for an asynchronous method to finish. What you need is to add a completion handler to your method:

```
func getDayData(completion: @escaping ([Item]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    Firestore.firestore()
        .collection("Users")
        .document("pK0tVBXvbFNhTZic3PIM")
        .collection("Log")
        .document("18-06-2020")
        .collection("Items")
        .getDocuments() { querySnapshot, error in
        let items = querySnapshot?.documents.map {
            Item(id: $0.documentID,
                 item: $0.get("Item") as? String ?? "",
                 category: $0.get("Category") as? String ?? "",
                 pieces: $0.get("Pieces") as? Int ?? 0)
        }
        completion(items, error)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
getDayData { items, error in
    guard let items = items else { 
        print(error ?? "nil")
        return 
    }
    // use items here

}
```

Comment: What if I then want to display a list of those items? I try getDayData { items, err in
                guard let items = items else {
                    print(err ?? "nil")
                    return
                }
                List(items){ item in
                    ZStack{
                        Text(item.item) //OTHER STUFF...
                    }
                }.padding(.trailing)
            }, but I get the error Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Comment: I am not used to SwiftUI but try  `List {`  `Text("Items")`  `ForEach(items) { item in` `Text(item.item)`  `}` `}` or maybe `List {` `Text("Items")`  `ForEach(0..<items.count) { index in` `Text(items[index].item)`  `}` `}`